# Classifying a numeric variable as high or low

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have one feature in my dataset that I would like to classify as high or low. The dataset itself contains 34 features and the feature I want to classify as high or low is a numeric and is in the last column labeled "absoluteupwardmobility". I can't copy and paste the whole dataset because it's over 28,000 observations and contains 34 features. I will paste the last 8 columns and first 22 rows

```
medianchildincome   parentincomep75 childincomep75  parentincomep90  childincomep90 parentincomep99 childincomep99  absoluteupwardmobility
31900   87700   62100   121600  90400   227400  158000  38.4
31900   87700   62100   121600  90400   227400  158000  38.4
31900   87700   62100   121600  90400   227400  158000  38.4
31900   87700   62100   121600  90400   227400  158000  38.4
31900   87700   62100   121600  90400   227400  158000  38.4
31900   87700   62100   121600  90400   227400  158000  38.4
31900   87700   62100   121600  90400   227400  158000  38.4
31900   87700   62100   121600  90400   227400  158000  38.4
31900   87700   62100   121600  90400   227400  158000  38.4
30200   90500   59500   135600  93900   444500  194500  39.6
30200   90500   59500   135600  93900   444500  194500  39.6
30200   90500   59500   135600  93900   444500  194500  39.6
30200   90500   59500   135600  93900   444500  194500  39.6
30200   90500   59500   135600  93900   444500  194500  39.6
30200   90500   59500   135600  93900   444500  194500  39.6
30200   90500   59500   135600  93900   444500  194500  39.6
30200   90500   59500   135600  93900   444500  194500  39.6
30200   90500   59500   135600  93900   444500  194500  39.6
22400   60800   44600   105600  75800   235700  153400  36.1
22400   60800   44600   105600  75800   235700  153400  36.1
22400   60800   44600   105600  75800   235700  153400  36.1
```

Notice that the absoluteupwardmobility varies: 38.4, 39.6, 36.1, etc. The range of values for absoluteupwardmobility is 23.7 to 63.8. I would like to write an algorithm that learns whether to classify these numbers as high or low. Clearly, 63.8 would be classified as high and 23.7 would be classified as low, but I wouldn't know what to classify say 39.6 as?
Would I write a Linear threshold unit algorithm? I want to transform the absoluteupwardmobility feature into a categorical variable that says either high or low instead of a numeric value but I don't know where to start.

So far all I have is:

```
  import numpy as np
  import pandas as pd
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  #   Read csv file
  df = pd.read_csv('raw_data_for_project2.csv')
  y  =  df[['absoluteupwardmobility']]   # Get last column
  X  =  df[df.columns.difference(['absoluteupwardmobility'])]    # X    includes columns 0,1,2,...,33
```

Comment: High or low compared to what? Are you looking to split on the median or something? Are you saying the distribution is bimodal and you need to cluster the values? It's unclear what you're looking for exactly.

Comment: Note that this is probably overkill for machine learning. "High" and "Low" are subjective. I doubt that the output would ever be better than working out the mean of all values and saying it's high or low if above/below the mean. You can always elaborate on that as a baseline analysis taking into account a distribution, but machine learning is unlikely to yield anything exceptional for you beyond standard mathematics. Don't over-complicate.

Comment: high or low compared to the numbers contained in that variable. Do you think I should just split by the median? The median is 43, so I can easily generate a new variable that is high if absoluteupwardmobility>= 43 and low if absoluteupwardmobility<43

Comment: @Maria That's why your default approach should be mathematical and not left to the mercy of algorithms that are expected to solve problems beyond absolute mathematical formulas. ML should be viewed as something to be used where traditional approaches fail; I could always get a machine to *learn* multiplication but it would only be an approximation to the simple approaches we have already. In this case you're looking to cluster a continuous variable...

Answer (score 0):

Start by plotting an histogram of that column, and determine what kind of distribution it is. If it is a Normal distribution `N(mu, sigma)`, you could classify as high anything that is above the `mean + n * sigma`, where sigma is the standard deviation, and `n` a factor of your choice, e.g. n = 2 or 3 are popular choices.

For the learning part, you could make an algorithm that learns from a set of high/low given classifications what that multiplier should be to match the common accepted range of "high" and "low".